# svm confusion_matrix 'too many values to unpack'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I've trained an SVM model and try to create a confusion matrix to evaluate it.
Therefore I make predictions with the test data and compare the prediction with the target class of the test data.

I have about 1000 data records, and Test data is nearly 300 data records.
I defined nine classes/labels.

The characteristics are normalized from -1 to 1 and all are float type.
A row of the array A represents each data record, and the target class is stored in array B.
I split those arrays into train and test data by a ratio of 70:30.

It's a simple code, but I don't have any idea right now.
One possibility could be to make a prediction and a confusion matrix for every data record of the test data and store the results in a list. After iterating over all data records, I could build the mean of all stored elements?

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve my problem?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Apr  5 10:50:47 2019

@author: mattdoe
"""

from data_preprocessor_db import data_storage # validation data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from numpy import array
import pickle



# for seperation of data_storage
# Link_ID = list()
Input, Output = list(), list()

# seperate data_storage in Input and Output data
for items in data_storage:
    # Link_ID = items[0] # identifier not needed
    Input.append((float(items[1]), float(items[2]), float(items[3]), float(items[4]), float(items[5]), float(items[6]), float(items[7]), float(items[8]), float(items[9]))) # Input: all characteristics
    Output.append(float(items[10])) # Output: scenario_class 1 to 9

# Input tuple to array
A = array(Input)

# normalise array between 0 and 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaledA = scaler.fit_transform(A)

# Output tuple to array
B = array(Output)

# split train and test data; ration: 70:30
# shuffle = False: doesn't sort data randomly
# shuffle = True: default: sorts data randomly
A_train, A_test, B_train, B_test = train_test_split(A, B, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True, random_state=40)

# create model
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)

# fit model
model.fit(A_train, B_train)

# get support vectors
# model.support_vectors_

# get indices of support vectors
# model.support_

# get number of support vectors for each class
# model.n_support_

filename = 'ml_svm.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# test to all data records
# result = loaded_model.score(A, B)

# test with test data
# score represents the mean accuracy of given test data and labels
result = loaded_model.score(A_test, B_test) # relative 
print(result)

# confusion matrix compares true value with predicted value
# true value <--> predicted value
predicted = model.predict(A_test)
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(B_test, predicted, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).ravel()
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-8649dd873bbd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML/ml_svm.py', wdir='C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML/ml_svm.py", line 75, in <module>
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(B_test, predicted, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).ravel()

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: confusion_matrix is returning the matrix. Using ravel you reshape the matrix into a vector. The dimension of the vector is depending on the matrix size (so in the documentation they show for the [binary case](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), so they have 4 elements), but in your case the matrix dimension is depending on the labels I guess (most likely NxN labels). So maybe store the result on a vector if you don't know beforehand matrix size (so `confusion_vector = confusion_matrix(..` instead of `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(..` ?

Comment: I think you should put it in an answer @elgordorafiki

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to elgordorafiki.
The solution with confusion_vector = confusion_matrix(...) works fine.

Without .ravel(), I now receive a 9x9 matrix.

Are the results on the diagonal all correctly values and all out of diagonal incorrect values? So each column and each row represents one class? Which are the predicted class? The columns or the rows?

How do I have to understand the result?

My result looks like:

```
[[ 35   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 177   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  3   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0]
 [  4   6   0   0   1   1   1   0  14]]
```

In my case, it seems class 3 and 4 have issues with class 1 and 2.